# iPhone app compilation failed for simulator: llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 255

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

My teammate compiled the application with a new branch of Restkit, and it works fine on his machine. After I pulled the new code, I was unable to run it in simulator mode anymore.

There is some error with the vendor code in the restkit.

I tried e solutions discussed in other qns: changing the architecture, valid architecture, compiler (to llvm 2.1), and a whole host of other settings.

But nothing seems to work. Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

The only key difference in our configuration is that he has installed ios5 on his xcode, while i do not have it

```
CompileC /Users/mingyeow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/onethingaday-espywbsoeffyaedhqzaoogguqyci/Build/Intermediates/RestKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RestKitJSONParser+NXJSON.build/Objects-normal/armv6/NXJsonParser.o Vendor/NXJSON/NXJsonParser.m normal armv6 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42
    cd /Users/mingyeow/tmp/DailyMus.es/RestKit
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -x objective-c -arch armv6 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -DDEBUG -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -fexceptions -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40300 -iquote /Users/mingyeow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/onethingaday-espywbsoeffyaedhqzaoogguqyci/Build/Intermediates/RestKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RestKitJSONParser+NXJSON.build/RestKitJSONParserNXJSON-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/mingyeow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/onethingaday-espywbsoeffyaedhqzaoogguqyci/Build/Intermediates/RestKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RestKitJSONParser+NXJSON.build/RestKitJSONParserNXJSON-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/mingyeow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/onethingaday-espywbsoeffyaedhqzaoogguqyci/Build/Intermediates/RestKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RestKitJSONParser+NXJSON.build/RestKitJSONParserNXJSON-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/mingyeow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/onethingaday-espywbsoeffyaedhqzaoogguqyci/Build/Intermediates/RestKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RestKitJSONParser+NXJSON.build/RestKitJSONParserNXJSON-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/mingyeow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/onethingaday-espywbsoeffyaedhqzaoogguqyci/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -IVendor/NSJSON -I/Users/mingyeow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/onethingaday-espywbsoeffyaedhqzaoogguqyci/Build/Intermediates/RestKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RestKitJSONParser+NXJSON.build/DerivedSources/armv6 -I/Users/mingyeow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/onethingaday-espywbsoeffyaedhqzaoogguqyci/Build/Intermediates/RestKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RestKitJSONParser+NXJSON.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/mingyeow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/onethingaday-espywbsoeffyaedhqzaoogguqyci/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -c /Users/mingyeow/tmp/DailyMus.es/RestKit/Vendor/NXJSON/NXJsonParser.m -o /Users/mingyeow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/onethingaday-espywbsoeffyaedhqzaoogguqyci/Build/Intermediates/RestKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RestKitJSONParser+NXJSON.build/Objects-normal/armv6/NXJsonParser.o

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/
bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 255
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exit code 255 means a file was not found, usually an executable like `ld` is missing from `/Developer/usr/bin`.  To find out which file it cannot find open up a Terminal, and manually run these 4 commands (from the error log):

```
cd /Users/mingyeow/tmp/DailyMus.es/RestKit
export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
export PATH="/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -x objective-c -arch armv6 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -DDEBUG -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -fexceptions -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40300 -iquote /Users/mingyeow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/onethingaday-espywbsoeffyaedhqzaoogguqyci/Build/Intermediates/RestKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RestKitJSONParser+NXJSON.build/RestKitJSONParserNXJSON-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/mingyeow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/onethingaday-espywbsoeffyaedhqzaoogguqyci/Build/Intermediates/RestKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RestKitJSONParser+NXJSON.build/RestKitJSONParserNXJSON-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/mingyeow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/onethingaday-espywbsoeffyaedhqzaoogguqyci/Build/Intermediates/RestKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RestKitJSONParser+NXJSON.build/RestKitJSONParserNXJSON-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/mingyeow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/onethingaday-espywbsoeffyaedhqzaoogguqyci/Build/Intermediates/RestKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RestKitJSONParser+NXJSON.build/RestKitJSONParserNXJSON-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/mingyeow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/onethingaday-espywbsoeffyaedhqzaoogguqyci/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -IVendor/NSJSON -I/Users/mingyeow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/onethingaday-espywbsoeffyaedhqzaoogguqyci/Build/Intermediates/RestKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RestKitJSONParser+NXJSON.build/DerivedSources/armv6 -I/Users/mingyeow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/onethingaday-espywbsoeffyaedhqzaoogguqyci/Build/Intermediates/RestKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RestKitJSONParser+NXJSON.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/mingyeow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/onethingaday-espywbsoeffyaedhqzaoogguqyci/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -c /Users/mingyeow/tmp/DailyMus.es/RestKit/Vendor/NXJSON/NXJsonParser.m -o /Users/mingyeow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/onethingaday-espywbsoeffyaedhqzaoogguqyci/Build/Intermediates/RestKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RestKitJSONParser+NXJSON.build/Objects-normal/armv6/NXJsonParser.o
```

Then it will tell you the exact file it is looking for that is missing.

---

Im guessing something is missing from `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin`, if you recently upgraded to xcode 4.2 and still have xcode 4.1 installed I suggest copying everything from `/Developer-4.1/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/` to `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/` but without overwriting/replacing anything, just copy everything that is in the 4.1 dir but not in the `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin`.

---

According to [this article](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=3062) this is how to fix a missing `execvp`:

Check out your build configuration. The Architectures probably have an inherited `$(ARCHS_…)` value which can fire a build error:

1. Navigate to Build Settings in Xcode and check out values in the Architectures group.
2. Remove “VALID ARCH” entry from Architectures field to reset settings. Use `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)`, or `armv6`, `armv7` values as you wish. `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)` should show `armv6 armv7`.
3. Repeat these steps at your dependent projects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried running it, and this is what i got. essentially execvp is missing

llvm-gcc-4.2: error trying to exec '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/arm-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2': execvp: No such file or directory

Comment: @mingyeow - To fix a missing execvp, check my answer edit, or see this article here: http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=3062

Comment: I tried that before, and just did it again.  it does not seem to work. still fails for the same reason. I have attached a screenshot of my config

Comment: In that case, see if the file `execvp` is in `/Developer/usr/bin/` and copy it to `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/`.if its not in `/Developer/usr/bin`, look in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Where is your screen shot, @mingyeow?