# Xcode Build error, arm-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1 execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, llvm, xcode4.3

After upgrading to Xcode 4.3.2. I'm getting a metric ton of build errors.

A whole line of them are error code 255

```
gcc-4.2: error trying to exec '/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1': execvp: No such file or directory
Command /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 255
```

I noticed that there is no `/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1` file on my machine. Could this be the source of the problem?

Comment: Yes, try to reinstall the sdk...

Comment: how do you reinstall? I used the AppStore version of Xcode. Do I delete it and re-download?

Comment: [Check this answer also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830263/iphone-app-compilation-failed-for-simulator-llvm-gcc-4-2-failed-with-exit-code)

Answer (score 2):

What's the output of this command?

```
$ printenv | grep "CC="
```

It might be honoring your C Compiler (CC) selection. I was getting similar errors (through cocoapods) and doing an

```
$ export CC=
```

fixed it for me.